# Data not reading properly using shorts but is usings ints. Buffer?

Tags: c, variables, unions

```
#include <stdio.h>


union memory{
    unsigned char byte[64000];
};


int main() {
    FILE* file;
    union memory mem;
    unsigned short address;
    unsigned short id;
    char rdwr[256], wb[256];
    file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    while (fscanf(file,"%x %x %s %s", &address, &id, rdwr, wb) != EOF)
    {

        printf("%x %x %s %s\n", address, id, rdwr, wb);
        id = mem.byte[address];
        printf("%s\n", mem.byte[address]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input of test.txt

1000 34 W B

1201 AB W B

1202 FF R B

1203 45 R B

1204 A9 R B

1205 B7 W B

1206 89 W B

Output of test.txt with address and id as shorts

- 0 34 W B
- (null)
- 0 ab W B
- (null)
- 0 ff R B
- (null)
- 0 45 R B
- (null)
- 0 a9 R B
- (null)
- 0 b7 W B
- (null)
- 0 89 W B
- (null)

Output of test.txt with address and id as ints

- 1000 34 W B
- (null)
- 1201 ab W B
- (null)
- 1202 ff R B
- (null)
- 1203 45 R B
- (null)
- 1204 a9 R B
- (null)
- 1205 b7 W B
- (null)
- 1206 89 W B
- (null)

Hello, so my main issue is that I am trying to read in hexidecimal values using shorts. Since a short is 2 bytes I would assume reading the address which is 4 nibbles = 2 bytes would be fine. I think I am running into some buffering with scanf? I am not sure of the correct term.  It doesn't make sense to me that I need an int to store 2 bytes or less worth of data. My second issue is I do not understand why my union is not storing the byte when I insert it. I am using a union as later on I need to use the same memory for other functions in the program such as words and need an overlay. If anyone could point me in the right direction to solve this issue that would be great. Ideally I'd like to use shorts, but if ints are required I can live with it.

Thanks!

Comment: For your second issue, do you want `mem.byte[address] = id` instead of `id = mem.byte[address]`? If not, I don't understand why you think `mem.byte[address] ` contains anything.

Comment: pretty sure you want `"%hx"` there instead of `"%x"`. From the [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3p.html): "`h` Specifies that a following `d, i, o, u, x, X`, or `n` conversion specifier applies to an argument with type pointer to `short` or `unsigned short`." And for `x`: " ... In the absence of a size modifier (like `h`), the application shall ensure that the corresponding argument is a pointer to `unsigned`.

Comment: Thank you for the %h fix I tried %hh and it didnt work but i guess that would be for reading two bytes... Also for the union issue I realize I was trying to read a location that had nothing in it....

Comment: `%hhx`  is for reading an `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 3):

The `%x` format specifier expects an `unsigned int *` as an argument.  You're instead passing a `unsigned short *`.  These types are incompatible, and using the wrong format specifier triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What is *probably* happening is that since an `unsigned int` is likely 4 bytes on your system and an `unsigned short` is 2 bytes, by using the wrong format specifier `scanf` is writing 4 bytes when only 2 bytes are available to be written, resulting in adjacent objects being overwritten.

To read in an `unsigned short`, you want to use `%hx`.

Also, `fscanf` returns the number of objects read, so you want to continue reading as long as you get 4 objects.

```
while (fscanf(file,"%hx %hx %s %s", &address, &id, rdwr, wb) == 4)
```